# Open app from alertcontroller action - Swift Error

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

So I have written some code, which is supposed to open an app called MobilePay. The problem is that my code won't be accepted in SWIFT when i try to make a else stament. Can somebody tell me what is wrong? - SWIFT tells me that there is an error.
The error is that it expects somekind of expression

```
@IBAction func Invoker(sender: AnyObject) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Betal", message: "Vælg en af nedstående betalingsmulighed", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    let ok1 = UIAlertAction(title: "MobilePay", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

    let url = NSURL(string: "mobilepay://")


    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) == true

    {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)

    } else {


    }


    let  cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Annuller", style: .Destructive) { (action) -> Void in


    }

    alertController.addAction(ok1)
    alertController.addAction(cancel)



    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)




    }

}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the error? And what exactly is the complete error message?

Comment: The error is that it expects somekind of expression, I can't to seem what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your braces are messed up:

```
@IBAction func Invoker(sender: AnyObject) 
{
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Betal", message: "Vælg en af nedstående betalingsmulighed", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    let ok1 = UIAlertAction(title: "MobilePay", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        let url = NSURL(string: "mobilepay://")!

        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url)
        {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Unable to open url
        }
    }) // You were missing this brace

    let  cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Annuller", style: .Destructive) { (action) -> Void in

        // Respond to the cancel action
    }

    alertController.addAction(ok1)
    alertController.addAction(cancel)

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// You had an extra brace here
```

Comment: Indentation usually helps, that seems to be his issue.

Comment: I edited your answer to add also the missing `)`, note that the closure in `ok1` is not a trailing closure.